# how to import once data with same value into SQLite with Jquery

Tags: jquery, sqlite, insert

Hi I have the following data

```
1    aaaa       
2    bbbb     
1    aaaa
3    cccc
2    bbbb
3    cccc
```

I want to import the above data to a SQLite like this

```
1    aaaa
2    bbbb
3    cccc
```

The same numbers must be imported once.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the table with:

```
CREATE TABLE T1 
ID     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
C1     VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE
```

And then use the

```
insert or replace into T1 (C1) values ( ... )
```